# Limit user options on CREATE / ALTER database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to limit the database settings that a user can edit, lets say auto grow and owner settings.

For example I want a user to be only able to modify tables, functions, stored procedures, but not to modify the settings i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can GRANT specific object permissions (existing database objects) without giving them db_owner.

BOL:  ms-help://MS.SQLCC.v9/MS.SQLSVR.v9.en/tsqlref9/html/c001c2e7-d092-43d4-8fa6-693b3ec4c3ea.htm